# Roots of complex numbers

Tags: equation-solving, complex

My exercise is to find $n$ roots of a rank $n$ of a complex number. Here is my code:

```
  roots[number_, n_] := 
     Module[{a = Re[number], b = Im[number], complex = number, zkList, 
       phi, zk, k},
      For[k = 0, k < n, k++,
       phi = Solve[{Sin[phi] == (a/Arg[number]), 
             Cos[phi] == (b/Arg[number])}, phi][[1, All, 2]][[1]] /. 
         C[1] -> 0;
       zk = (Arg[number])^(1/n)*(Cos[(phi + 2*k*Pi)/n] + 
           I*Sin[(phi + 2*k*Pi)/n]);
       zkList[k + 1] = zk] ; 
      Print[zkList];]
```

When I try to run this by:

```
roots[1 + I, 4]
```

It throws me errors: Part::partw: Part 1 of {} does not exist (times 3),

General::stop: Further output of Part::partw will be suppressed during this calculation. (times 1)

This is because of this line:

```
phi = Solve[{Sin[phi] == (a/Arg[number]), 
             Cos[phi] == (b/Arg[number])}, phi][[1, All, 2]][[1]] /. 
         C[1] -> 0;
```

but I don't know how to fix. Also, this line works outside the `roots` function with numbers substituted.

Comment: `Solve` is returning `{}`, indicating there are no solutions to the system.  You have two equations and one unknown, which is probably the reason.

Comment: You can see that the solutions to the individual equations have no common roots with `Solve[{#, -2 Pi < Re@phi < 2 Pi}, phi] & /@ {Sin[phi] == (1/Arg[1 + I]), Cos[phi] == (1/Arg[1 + I])}`

Comment: How could it be when we got system for my example with $\sin x=1/sqrt(2)$ and $\cos x =1/sqrt(2)$ since $a=b=1$ and so $\arg z=sqrt(2)$. The solution is $\pi/4$

Comment: Execute `Arg[1 + I]` -- maybe you meant `Abs[1 + I]`? (That is, `Abs[number]` in the code for `root`.)

Comment: Oh man, I totally mixed up mathematical concepts. I have to do the program again. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome.  You'll still have some problems because you assign `phi` a value and try to use it as a variable (with no value) in `Solve`. The second time through the loop, `Solve` will complain. You could use two different variables to fix it: `phi0 = Solve[..., phi]...`

Comment: Yea, probably you are right, but as long as I have Arg[z] I dont have to compute phi by hand anymore. :D

Comment: Of course. :) I was wondering why you weren't using that, but sometimes people want to solve an equation a certain way instead of using a built-in function.